# Change language of SwitchPreference

Tags: android, localization, internationalization

I have an Android app which is only available in English. Accordingly, all of the UI that's under my control appears in English only, regardless of what language the user has set their device to. The issue is with `SwitchPreference`s on my app's Settings screen; the "on"/"off" labels on the switches themselves are getting localized, presenting the user with a mixed-language UI.

See screenshot at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ry4aCYVaqoUkFlZW9XT2VLVFE/view?usp=sharing

Is there any way to override the system localization of this element?

Notes:

1. I'm not that bothered about this myself, but the app is being rejected by Samsung's app store certification team on this basis. So I do need to fix it if possible.
2. Please don't respond by saying "localize your app so that there's not a mix". Apart from other localization issues (which are out of scope here), it just isn't possible for me to localize to all the langauges that the Android OS supports.

Comment: You might consider just rolling back to `CheckBoxPreference`. There are also various "force the locale" instructions for the whole app that you'll find here on Stack Overflow, though I have not found them. Or, you could fork `SwitchPreference` and use your own `Switch` that hard-codes the labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, Mark, but it turns out there's an easier way. I just added the following attributes to the SwitchPreference elements in the XML which defines my settings screen:

```
            android:switchTextOff="OFF"
            android:switchTextOn="ON"
```

*Voila*, the switch labels are un-localized. RTFM FTW! :^)